# Continue running a function in minimized state in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, microsoft-metro

I have a CreateSchedule() function which execute when I open app.

```
 private async static Task<int> CreateSchedule()
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime planTill = now.AddMinutes(15);
            do
            {
                await DoSomeWork();
                now = DateTime.Now;
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            } while (now < planTill);

            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This function runs continuously (I have used do-while loop) when the app is in active state or in foreground state. But when I minimize or press Back or Start button on WP, this function won't execute anymore.

So is there any ways to execute that function continuously even when the app is minimized or Start or Back button is pressed.

I have tried using BackgroundTask but that seems to execute only between 0-15 minutes from the time of registration which is not my requirement.

Please suggest some if there are any Threads we can run in background in Windows Phone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it *exactly* you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi Shawn, I'm trying to start the background task immediately after registering it on WP 8.1. But it doesn't seem to do that. So i'm looking some other approaches to run background thread and keeps it continuing even if the app is minimized.

Comment: As @kristian said, you cannot run code **forever** when your app is minimized. You also cannot start you background task *in the background*. You can however create an instance of the task and call the run method. Or extract the code to a common core class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design that you can't run code in the background. The only option is a `BackgroundTask` which has many limitations (must be on lock screen, every 15 minutes etc.) as you already stated.

So the short answer is you can't.

You can read more about background tasks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kristian. Are there any threads available for WP8.1 that we can run for some time in background?

Comment: You can run a background task every 15 minutes for 2 seconds of CPU time. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks. BackgroundTask doesn't seem to work as per my need.